# Where do I pay tax if I am a UK resident but work remotely in Malta?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, malta

I will be a UK resident as of January 2016 but I work remotely for a Malta company. Specifically, I will live in London and work from my house for a Maltese company. Where do I have to pay taxes?

Answer (score 2):

If you live in the UK and you have income from abroad, you will normally be expected to pay UK income tax.

> You may need to pay UK Income Tax on your foreign income, eg:
>
> - wages if you work abroad
> - foreign investments and savings interest
> - rental income on overseas property
> - income from pensions held overseas
>
> Foreign income is anything from outside England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland. The Channel Islands and the Isle of Man are classed as foreign.

See the UK Government website at https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income (There's no point in reproducing everything here, particularly as tax rules change from time to time and they are complex, depending on many circumstances, not all of which you may have included in your question).

Note that the UK doesn't normally levy tax on taxed income, so if for some reason you are taxed at source you can apply for tax relief in the UK.