# Where to pay tax when working remotely from the UK for a foreign company?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, foreign-income, working-at-home, malta

There are similar [questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/55023/60932) but I believe my circumstances are slightly different.

I am a British citizen, from birth, and have been living in Malta for over a year while working for several companies full time paying tax there. Next month I will be starting full time employment for another Maltese company but after 2 weeks I will be moving back to the UK for 5 months before returning to Malta.

I will be getting paid in EUR to my Maltese bank account and intended to transfer to my UK account as required for rent (I am not a home owner).
I have both a Maltese social security number and UK national insurance number.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I really don't want to pay tax twice.

Comment: `I really don't want to pay tax twice` You won't be paying tax twice because of double taxation treaty. `I will be moving back to the UK for 5 months` This will be taken care of by your employer. They need to deduct the correct taxes.  https://www.gov.uk/tax-uk-income-live-abroad/taxed-twice